# Record is not Added in to the databse using Jsp Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

i am creating a simple crud using jsp mysql but record is not added in to the database.i tried this for 3 days but i couldn't solve the problem.i don't know what was a problem what i tried so far i attached below. Form design and Student.java class consist of all data and StudentDAO database is there add.jsp add the data in to the database.

**Form**

```
<div class="form-group" align="left">
                    <label class="form-label">Student Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Student Name" id="stname" name="stname" size="30px" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" align="left">
                    <label class="form-label">Course</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Course" id="course" name="course" size="30px" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" align="left">
                    <label class="form-label">Fee</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Fee" id="fee" name="fee" size="30px" required>
                </div>

                  <div class="card" align="right">
                    <button type="button" class=" btn btn-info" id="save" onclick="addProject()">Registation
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="clear"   onclick="clear()">Close</button>
                </div>
```

**Student.java**

```
 public class Student {

        private String stname;
         private String course;
         private int fee;

        public Student(String stname, String course, int fee) {
            this.stname = stname;
            this.course = course;
            this.fee = fee;
        }

        public String getStname() {
            return stname;
        }

        public void setStname(String stname) {
            this.stname = stname;
        }

        public String getCourse() {
            return course;
        }

        public void setCourse(String course) {
            this.course = course;
        }

        public int getFee() {
            return fee;
        }

        public void setFee(int fee) {
            this.fee = fee;
        }
```

StudentDAO.java

```
public class StudentDAO {

    Connection connection;
    PreparedStatement pst;

    public StudentDAO() {
        String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/studcrud";
        String dbUser = "root";
        String dbPassword = "";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, dbUser, dbPassword);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
public int insertUser(Student stud) throws SQLException, 
        ClassNotFoundException {

        String sql = "insert into records(name,course,fee)values(?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1, stud.getStname());
        statement.setString(2, stud.getCourse());
                statement.setInt(3, stud.getFee());

                 int row=  statement.executeUpdate();
                 return row;
    }
```

Add.jsp

```
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONArray"%>
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>


        <%

       String stname = request.getParameter("stname");
       String course = request.getParameter("course");
       int  fee = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("fee"));

       //fill it up in a Student Bean
       Student stud = new Student(stname,course,fee);


       StudentDAO stu = new StudentDAO();
       int rows = stu.insertUser(stud); 

      String message;


      if(rows==0)
      {
           message = "success";

      }
      else
      {
          message = "Failed";
      }
```

Comment: int rowcount = connection.executeUpdate("insert into records(name,course,fee)values("+stud.getStname()+",'"+stud.getStname()+",'''+stud.getFee() +')");

Comment: i tired this but not worked

Comment: can you step and see what the rowcount is after the execute? and are the 3 parameters set as expected?

Comment: executeUpdate shown error

Comment: why if use preparestatement any problem here sir

Comment: what is  `onclick="addProject()"` this for ? How do you submit your `form` ?

Comment: serilaze all fom data into send to Add.jsp

Comment: @mayukobi does it send your data properly ? see if data are not null ,also you have set values using `constructor` ? why do you need `set` method then ?.

Comment: so the i need so constructor  no need set

Comment: Mayu - what was the error shown on executeUpdate?